# symfony modify choices in collection after set data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm trying to build a form, for user to enter his answers to an exam.
Form consists of Collection of answers looking like this:

```
class UserExamFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answers', CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => UserExamAnswerType::class,
                    'allow_delete' => false,
                    'allow_add' => false,
                ])->add('submit', SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Zapisz',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'btn-success',
                    ],
                ]
            )->add('finish', SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Zapisz i zakończ',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'btn-danger confirmation',
                        'data-message' => 'Czy na pewno chcesz zakończyć test? Nie będzie możliwości poprawy odpowiedzi.'
                    ],
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => UserExam::class,
        ]);
    }
}
class UserExamAnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // dump($builder->getData()); === null
        $builder
            ->add('answer', EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Answer::class,
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository) {
                        return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('a');
                    }
                ]);

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            dump($event->getData()); // !== null
            //modify choices
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ExamAnswer::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How to modify choices in the commented line?
I'd like the choices  to be affected by the object passed into the form.
In the line `dump($event->getData()); // !== null` I get exactly the object I need to determine choices but I haven't found any info on it - only dynamically adding a field.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it by adding an element right before Symfony sets the data on form.
Maybe someone will profit from this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $event->getForm()
            ->add('answer', EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Answer::class,
                    'choice_value' => 'id',
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'choices' => $event->getData()->getQuestion()->getAnswers()
                ]);
    });
}
```